# EE removes third member group from all channel posting privileges

Tags: ee2, channel-entries, member-management

I am running into an issue with EE. I currently have 3 member groups set up. These are:

1. Super Admins - who have full access to the admin panel
2. Staff- who have limited access to the admin panel
3. Guests - who need channel posting privileges to create member accounts via Zoo Visitor

When i assign the posting privileges to the guest member group, all channel posting privileges for "Staff" are removed and visa versa. Is EE limited to 2 member groups per channel for posting privileges?

I remember a few years back adding a hack to the EE files to lift the limit, but can;t remember where this was added.

Any thoughts and assistance appreciated.

Many thanks
Ben

Comment: Exactly what version of EE are you using?

Additionally I have ran into this issue, but it actually was a problem with EE writing to the Database. Can you please confirm in your database that these member groups have the appropriate permissions? If not you may have to manually do it in the database.

Comment: Hi Justin.. Yeah you are right, this is something to do with EE writing to the database. I manually edited the database myself and all is working perfectly now! Thanks.